# position text in top of EditText

Tags: android

i have this for an xml Edittext , which i may made a little bigger allowing the user to type a longer text , but the `hint` is always showing up in the middle of the text Area , and i want to put it in the top of the Edit Text , How can id do this ?

```
<EditText 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textlines"
                android:hint="@string/text"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"/>
```

Comment: Did you try `android:gravity`..?

Comment: yes , and it didn't work .

Comment: Try this too..set the `android:includeFontPadding` attribute to false in your XML

Comment: Tried it , didn't work always .

Comment: Try adding theese too in your xml file..` android:lines="5"   android:singleLine="false"` along with gravity..

Comment: even that is not working

Comment: Try chnaging `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the gravity to `top` and mask it with `left`

**sample:**

```
 <EditText 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:hint="I am hint"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"/>
```

**result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<EditText 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:minHeight="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/textlines"
                android:hint="@string/text"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"/>
```

Comment: this is more of a hack than a logical solution , is this the only way to do it  ?